# Troubleshooting overheating USB Hub

Tags: usb, temperature, usb-hub

I have a Maxxtro MX-UCZ USB 3.0 Hub and recently it started getting hot for no apparent reason. After opening the enclosure and looking at the board from both sides I have seen that all solder joints look normal, no obvious short circuits. After further inspection I realized that the chip is the part that gets really hot and thus heats everything else - as soon as the hub is plugged in, the chip gets unbearably hot, even when nothing is attached to the hub. Apart from getting extremely hot it still works fine. When I checked for continuity with my multimeter, I noticed a rather strange thing. All pins of the external power jack and the shields of the usb ports are connected together.

[Pictures here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4epsu.jpg)

The pins marked red are all connected together and showed resistance of 0 Ohms. Is this a sign that something else in the board is shorted? Pins of a power jack surely shouldn't be shorted like that.

Comment: Looks perfectly normal. Its the pin at the back of the socket which usually carries power.

Comment: Is it still overheating? What hub chip is there? VIA? TI?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that all the points you have indentified are GROUND, and they SHOULD be connected together.

I agree that the overheating symptom is NOT "normal".  Since those products are made with custom, proprietary, or otherwise unidentifable parts (like the chip) it is very doubtful that it is "repairable". And especially since there is no technical information (like schematic diagram) available.

Even if you could identify that the chip is bad, and you could acquire a proper replacement, it would require very tricky removal and replacement of a surface-mount part. And if you could do that, you wouldn't be here asking this question.  Very few people would attempt an SMD remove and replace for such a low-cost, essentially "throw-away" product.